# drupal 7 calculated field returns undefined index

Tags: drupal-7

Ok, struggling now after two hours - and I still cant get it.

I'm trying to average all of the fivestar ratings I have for a node using a computed field. But i'm struggling to simply access the other fields using entity!

In the body of the node, this works fine:

```
$test1 = $node->field_ae_stimclasswrk[und][0]['average'];
```

but in the computed field area, this doesn't work:

```
$entity_field[0]['value'] = $entity->field_ae_stimclasswrk[$entity->language]    [und][0]['average'];
```

Instead, when I save the node, I get this index error:

Notice: Undefined index: und in eval() (line 2 of...

It must be something syntax, but i'm completely out of ideas.

here is the field info:

```
   [field_ae_stimclasswrk] => Array
        (
            [und] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                            (
                            [user] => 80
                            [average] => 80
                            [count] => 1
                        )

                )

       )
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a tiny error in your code:

```
$entity->field_ae_stimclasswrk[$entity->language][und][0]['average'];
```

If you look at that closely you're actually trying to access the language element of the field twice, once with `$entity->language` and once with `und`.

It would probably be best to keep the code contextual so I would remove the `[und]` item in the code:

```
$entity->field_ae_stimclasswrk[$entity->language][0]['average'];
```

Comment: It returns this error after saving node: Notice: Undefined index: und

Comment: /home/greenabr/public_html/sites/all/modules/computed_field/computed_field.module(439) : eval()'d code).

Comment: Did you make the changes as suggested in the answer above?

Comment: Yes, I made the above changes. Humm.

Comment: try `print_r($entity->field_ae_stimclasswrk)` just to see what's actually in that variable

Comment: nothing prints - get this error: Notice: Undefined index: und in eval() (line 2 of /home/greenabr/public_html/sites/all/modules/computed_field/computed_field.module(439) : eval()'d code).
Notice: Undefined variable: entity in eval() (line 8 of /home/greenabr/public_html/modules/php/php.module(74) : eval()'d code).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in eval() (line 8 of /home/greenabr/public_html/modules/php/php.module(74) : eval()'d code).
Notice: Undefined variable: entity in eval() (line 8 of /home/greenabr/public_html/modules/php/php.module(74) : eval()'d code).
Noti

Comment: If nothing prints then the object doesn't exist, this is backed up by the `Trying to get property of non-object` notice you get. It seems `$entity` isn't getting passed to your code (even though the module's help text says otherwise). It could be because the module's still in development, the only thing I can really suggest is checking the [issue queue](http://drupal.org/project/issues/computed_field?categories=All) to see if anyone else has had the same problem, or perhaps file a new issue

Comment: Thank you for your support so far. Could you recommend an alternative solution for the goal I wish to achieve. I have 9 fivestar ratings associated to a node, and I would like to sort & display nodes based upon an average of all these ratings - and overall rating, if you would. I can jerry rig a solution for displaying it in the node- but how about sorting in Views 3?

Comment: I don't really use views I'm afraid, I always favour coding this sort of thing myself so I have complete control over performance/html output. I'd suggest jerry rigging it like you say, or, better yet, create a custom module to do it so your code is re-usable.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue. It was actually caused by a non-existent index inside `$entity->field_ref[$entity->language]`.

For me, `$entity->field_ref[$entity->language]` existed for all nodes but when you add an index inside that it causes a problem for any nodes that don't use the field.

`$entity->field_ref[$entity->language][0]` caused the issue (note the addition of the `[0]` index).

To solve your problem you could try:

```
$test1 = (isset($node->field_ae_stimclasswrk[$node->language][0]['average']))? $node->field_ae_stimclasswrk[$node->language][0]['average'] : NULL;
```

Or a little easier to read:

```
if (isset($node->field_ae_stimclasswrk[$node->language][0]['average'])){
  $test1 = $node->field_ae_stimclasswrk[$node->language][0]['average'];
} else {
  $test1 = NULL;
}
```

This way it will bypass any nodes that don't make use of the field.